# Unable to override docker compose variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

My `docker-compose.yml` file has a bunch of variables with default values that I want to override when running `docker compose up`:

```yaml
image: some-image:${TAG-latest}
  environment:
    SERVER_HOST: ${SERVER_HOST:-localhost}
```

I tried to override the `TAG` variable but it seems like there is no `-e` option for `docker compose up` so I did:

```bash
docker compose run -e TAG=1.0.0 service_name
```

This resulted in downloading the `latest` image though which isn't what I was expecting.

What's the proper way to do a `docker compose up` while overriding the default values `TAG` and `SERVER_HOST`?

Comment: This is due to a typo in your compose file: `${TAG-latest}` -> `${TAG:-latest}`